# How to do automatic payments (non-recurring) with Paypal

Tags: paypal

Ok, I'm wondering if there is any way that we can bill clients via Paypal automatically? Meaning like we can bill their accounts a certain amount without them having to do anything. I'm pretty sure I've seen other companies do something like this where the user has to agree to some agreement or something?

Use case is that we have a marketplace and was wondering if we could setup something like monthly auto-payments which would automatically bill the client whatever is owed to us from their selling fees. Sometimes they may owe nothing, other times they may owe $5 and other times they may owe $150 etc.

Can something like this be done with Paypal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using reference transaction  API https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/.